# Confusion understanding PHP namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces

I am learning about and implementing PHP namespaces.
Please refer to the following code:

```php
<?php

namespace Xicor\core;

class App {

  public function __construct() {

    $registry = Registry::getInstance();

    //TODO: init router

    //TODO: call controller@action
    $controllerName = 'Xicor\app\controllers\\'.'Index';
    $action = 'show';

    $controller = new $controllerName();
    $controller->$action();

  }

}
```

The above code works perfectly.

If I add `throw new Exception('Lorem Ipsum')` within the constructor, I'll get an error as expected. To make it work, I must use `throw new \Exception('Lorem Ipsum')` so that we are referring to the global namespace.

But, why does
`$controllerName = 'Xicor\app\controllers\\'.'Index';` successfully import the right class.

Why do I not have to use
`$controllerName = '\Xicor\app\controllers\\'.'Index';` (with \ prefixed)?

If it affects anything, here's my autoloader:

```php
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function($name) {
  //replace \ with DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
  $path = str_replace('\\', DS, $name);
  //replace Xicor with root
  $path = str_replace('Xicor', __DIR__, $path); // __DIR__ doesn't return a trailing slash
  //add .php at end
  $path .= '.php';

  if(file_exists($path)) {
    require_once($path);
  }
});
```

Comment: your doing `DIR__, $name);` it should be `DIR__, $path);`.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thanks for pointing it out. I've made the change in question.

Comment: Just wanted to check - are you sure 'Xicor\app\controllers\Index' does indeed resolve to 'Xicor\app\controllers\Index' and not a class 'Xicor\core\Index' ? It may be that I am not understanding the documentation, but based on how I read it it would resolve to the latter.

Comment: @MarkFisher Yes, just re-checked. I'm sure it is resolving to 'Xicor\app\controllers\Index'.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it. PHP will work in the current namespace within a class unless specified otherwise (a preceding \).

Example

```
namespace Bar;

class Foo {
    function __construct()
    {
        // references current namespace, looks for Bar\Baz;
        $baz = new Baz();
    }
}

class Baz {
    function __construct()
    {
        try {
            // do stuff

            // references global namespace
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }


    }

    function foo() {

        // This will prepend the current namespace to the class, in actual fact it will first look for "Bar\Bar\Foo"
        // When it isnt found, it will move on and look at spl_autoload_register to try to resolve this class,
        // Failing that you will get a ClassNotFoundException
        $foo = new Bar\Foo();
    }
}
```

Please see. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php
and https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.full for reference

Comment: Oh, this explains it. Before I can mark it as answer, can someone confirm that in the code above, it first looks for 'Xicor\core\Xicor\app\controllers\Index' but fails then falls back to spl_autoload_register(Xicor\app\controllers\Index)?

Comment: Although, on a side note, what's weird is, explicitly typed `Xicor\app\controllers\Index` won't resolve and the preceding \ becomes necessary.